# Double Link Router in React

Tags: reactjs, router

i have a react app with one Router and two Links, one link moves to App.js and the another to '/favoritos', my purpose is that the link to favorites make the route to App.js and next to /favoritos, i want to redirect or in simple words a way to make a double Link, that move first to localhost:3000 and continue to /favoritos

```
#This part move to app.js (localhost:3000)

<a  href="/" className="brand-logo" >   
<Link to = "/"><i className="material-icons"></i> </Link>Movie finder </a> 

#This part move to localhost:3000/favoritos

<ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down" >
<Link to="/favoritos" ><li onClick={ props.closeMovieInfo }> Favoritos </li> </Link>
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: When a user wants to go to /favoritos page, you want the user first to go to main page and then to be redirected to /favoritos page. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app router,

```
<Route
    path={'/'}
    component={YourComponent}
    exact={false}
/>
```

By setting `exact={false}`, you specify that every request will be redirected to your main page. In your main page, check the coming URL params from `props.match`. If it is the main page, render the current main page. If not, render the other page.

For another way, I don't know why you are trying this, but if you want to trigger a common function, you can write this function to your AppRouter